# Saving the added String item to ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am new to Java and Swing and I couldn't find a solution to the problem I have. I have a GUI which can add items to a combobox. I am trying to keep the added items in the combobox after the GUI is shut down and have the newly added items when it's launched again. Is there any easy way to do this?

Here is the code for the GUI:

```
package GUI1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class OnurComboBox extends JDialog implements 
ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox comboBox = null;
    private int comnum;
    public String combo;
//    final String[] theOptions = {
//  "Option 1", "Option 2", 
//        "Option 3", "Option 4", 
//  "Option 5", "Option 6"
//    };
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            OnurComboBox dialog = new OnurComboBox();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public OnurComboBox() {



        setTitle("Choose an Option");
        setSize(325, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                System.out.println("The item selected is: " + combo);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnOk.setBounds(66, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnOk);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBounds(165, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnCancel);

//        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(theOptions);
        Vector comboBoxItems=new Vector();
        comboBoxItems.add("A");
        comboBoxItems.add("B");
        comboBoxItems.add("C");
        comboBoxItems.add("D");
        comboBoxItems.add("E");
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboBoxItems);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
        comboBox.setBounds(10, 34, 187, 23);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        comboBox.addItemListener(this);
        desktopPane.add(comboBox);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
          combo = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
          comnum = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
          textField.setText(combo);
          }
          });

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 228, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(10, 103, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane txtpnSelected = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelected.setEditable(false);
        txtpnSelected.setText("Item Selected:");
        txtpnSelected.setBounds(10, 202, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelected);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!textField_1.getText().equals("")){
                      int a = 0;
                      for(int i = 0; i < comboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
                      if(comboBox.getItemAt(i).equals(textField_1.getText())){
                      a = 1;
                      break;
                      }
                      }
                      if (a == 1)
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Combobox already has this item.");
                      else
                     comboBox.addItem(textField_1.getText());
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item added to Combobox");
                      }
                      else{
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter text in the Text Box");
                      }
                      }
                      });

        btnAdd.setBounds(207, 103, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnAdd);

        JTextPane txtpnEnterTheOption = new JTextPane();
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setText("Enter the new option:");
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setEditable(false);
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setBounds(10, 80, 131, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnEnterTheOption);

        JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.getItemCount() > 0){
                    comboBox.removeItemAt(comnum);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item removed");}
                      else
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item not available");
            }
        });
        btnRemove.setBounds(207, 34, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnRemove);

        JTextPane txtpnSelectAnItem = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setText("Select an item from the list or add a new option");
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setBounds(10, 3, 289, 20);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelectAnItem);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
//            int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
//            display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
//                ClassLoader.getSystemResource(images[index])));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The edited and working code, which does the job, with the great help of "Alya'a Gamal":

```
package GUI1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class OnurComboBox1 extends JDialog implements 
ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox comboBox = null;
    private int comnum;
    public String combo;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    static String filePath = "t.txt";/////this text file have 
//    private PrintWriter out;
//    private BufferedReader input;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            OnurComboBox1 dialog = new OnurComboBox1();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public OnurComboBox1() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));  

        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t.txt", true)));

        setTitle("Choose an Option");
        setSize(325, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                System.out.println("The item selected is: " + combo);
                out.close();/////to close the text file
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnOk.setBounds(66, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnOk);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBounds(165, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnCancel);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    strings.add(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lineArray);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);

        comboBox.setBounds(10, 34, 187, 23);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        comboBox.addItemListener(this);
        desktopPane.add(comboBox);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
          combo = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
          comnum = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
          textField.setText(combo);
          }
          });

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 228, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(10, 103, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane txtpnSelected = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelected.setEditable(false);
        txtpnSelected.setText("Item Selected:");
        txtpnSelected.setBounds(10, 202, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelected);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!textField_1.getText().equals("")){
                      int a = 0;
                      for(int i = 0; i < comboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
                      if(comboBox.getItemAt(i).equals(textField_1.getText())){
                      a = 1;
                      break;
                      }
                      }
                      if (a == 1)
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Combobox already has this item.");
                      else
                     comboBox.addItem(textField_1.getText());
                     out.println(textField_1.getText());////this will add the new value in the text file
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item added to Combobox");
                      }
                      else{
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter text in the Text Box");
                      }
                      }
                      });

        btnAdd.setBounds(207, 103, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnAdd);

        JTextPane txtpnEnterTheOption = new JTextPane();
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setText("Enter the new option:");
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setEditable(false);
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setBounds(10, 80, 131, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnEnterTheOption);

        JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.getItemCount() > 0){
                    comboBox.removeItemAt(comnum);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item removed");}
                      else
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item not available");
            }
        });
        btnRemove.setBounds(207, 34, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnRemove);

        JTextPane txtpnSelectAnItem = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setText("Select an item from the list or add a new option");
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setBounds(10, 3, 289, 20);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelectAnItem);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
//            int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
//            display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
//                ClassLoader.getSystemResource(images[index])));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all don't use setBounds() to position and size components. Use a Layout Manager. So what exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to read/write to a file? Or are you asking how to know when the frame is being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text file to read and write from it

```
String filePath = "t.txt";/////this text file have
```

1- create text file and write your Vectot (A,B,C,D) each one in separated line on it

2-create two variables, one to read the text

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```

and the second to write on the file the value will be add  :

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t.txt", true)));
```

3- read this file in your `comboBox` , like that :

```
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                strings.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, file " + filePath + " didn't exist.");
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }

        String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lineArray);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
```

4- In  `btnAdd` button  Actionlistner add:

```
out.println(textField_1.getText());////this will add the new value in the text file
```

5- In  `btnOk` button Actionlistner  add:

```
out.close();/////to close the text file
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

class OnurComboBox extends JDialog implements
        ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox comboBox = null;
    private int comnum;
    public String combo;
//    final String[] theOptions = {
//  "Option 1", "Option 2", 
//        "Option 3", "Option 4", 
//  "Option 5", "Option 6"
//    };
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    String filePath = "t.txt";
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
public static PrintWriter out;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t.txt", true)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        OnurComboBox dialog = new OnurComboBox();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public OnurComboBox() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {



        setTitle("Choose an Option");
        setSize(325, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("The item selected is: " + combo);

                out.close();


                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnOk.setBounds(66, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnOk);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBounds(165, 153, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnCancel);

//        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(theOptions);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                strings.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, file " + filePath + " didn't exist.");
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }

        String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lineArray);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
        comboBox.setBounds(10, 34, 187, 23);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        comboBox.addItemListener(this);
        desktopPane.add(comboBox);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                combo = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                comnum = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                textField.setText(combo);
            }
        });

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 228, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(10, 103, 187, 23);
        desktopPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane txtpnSelected = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelected.setEditable(false);
        txtpnSelected.setText("Item Selected:");
        txtpnSelected.setBounds(10, 202, 89, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelected);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!textField_1.getText().equals("")) {
                    int a = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        if (comboBox.getItemAt(i).equals(textField_1.getText())) {
                            a = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (a == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Combobox already has this item.");
                    } else {
                        comboBox.addItem(textField_1.getText());
                    }

                    out.println(textField_1.getText());


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item added to Combobox");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter text in the Text Box");
                }
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setBounds(207, 103, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnAdd);

        JTextPane txtpnEnterTheOption = new JTextPane();
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setText("Enter the new option:");
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setEditable(false);
        txtpnEnterTheOption.setBounds(10, 80, 131, 23);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnEnterTheOption);

        JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    comboBox.removeItemAt(comnum);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item removed");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not available");
                }
            }
        });
        btnRemove.setBounds(207, 34, 92, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnRemove);

        JTextPane txtpnSelectAnItem = new JTextPane();
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setText("Select an item from the list or add a new option");
        txtpnSelectAnItem.setBounds(10, 3, 289, 20);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnSelectAnItem);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
//            int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
//            display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
//                ClassLoader.getSystemResource(images[index])));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting a "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" in the variable definitions and Eclipse cannot implement the solution automatically. Can you help me solve it? Also, should the text file be in the same path as the class, I am not sure if I defined the filepath variable properly. Should I include the full path somehow?

Comment: you need firts to create the text file "manually" and write your Vectot  on it then take this path and read it in java and the same text path to write again in it

Comment: I already did that without a problem. I am not sure where to put it and how to define the path variable though. should the text file be in the same path as the Java class so that it will get it automatically?

Comment: yes you can create this text file in your class path , and just use it's name like "t.txt"

Comment: O.K. I got that one but I still get the errors in 2 variables. "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" in BufferedReader. "Unhandled exception type IOException" in PrintWriter. Can you think of a solution?

Comment: this error mean the file is not exist , so sure you enter the correct path of the file , if you already create it in your classpath , so try "/t.txt"

Comment: Small update: I got the first exception by the help of Eclipse. But cannot get the "out" exception: "Unhandled exception type IOException". This is a compilation error by the way, do you think it searches for the file now before it's executed? I changed it to  "/t.txt" but still the same. I have the file in Eclipse bin for sure.

Comment: No , put it in you the  project directory :(

Comment: I also copied it there, it still gives the same error. I guess I should add a try and catch block, which I do not know how to do. I added the edited code to the question. Can you possibly show me how to handle the error? It is on the line starting with "PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("

Comment: Look , i will post you the whole code and it run ok with me , so try it , and then tell me

Comment: I tried running your code and I get the exact same errors. I think I just need to add a try and catch block to this line but I can't do it properly:
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter()  {          
     try {
     new FileWriter("t.txt", true);
     } catch (IOException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
     }
     
     
 );

Comment: OK , try it and try to google the error :) it will help you more than me

Comment: I am really sorry for all the trouble; but all I can do with try/catch blocks is sticking with default eclipse solutions.

Comment: Don't say sorry , we here to help each other :) , i see that you error in the file , so try to debug the code , and be sure that the file path is true , and try to make another project and test on it this code :`import java.io.*;

public class TestPrintWriter {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("///////file path", true)));
  pw.println("Sample String");
  int i = 10;
  pw.println(i);
 }
}` and then tell me what is the error ,

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help,  you are really incredibly helpful. I don't get an error with that one. I tried implementing it to the code; but I get syntax errors. How should I insert this: "try {
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t.txt", true)));
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();}
 } " Do I have to use the try/catch in a method?

Comment: this is the same code , and without try catch , so tell me what is the error??

Comment: Yes it is the same code, I am just trying to include it in a try/catch block. If I do not include it in a try/catch I get the old error "Unhandled exception type IOException". I am trying to ask how can I include that line in a try/catch block properly so that it will work?

Comment: I think the block needs to be in a method. I have put it in OnurComboBox() method. Seems to compile right now, but it is not reading the file now. The combobox starts all empty. I checked your code too, it is the same result, it runs with an empty combobox.

Comment: did you write in the file before you use it??, and when you add new value , ia add to  the file???

Comment: O.K. I got it working perfectly fine. Thank you for all your help. You were very kind to answer all of my questions. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest in your case is to write them to a file. Have a look at [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), to make file reading and writing easier. The best way is to have a sort of initialisation method which will read the file, populate it from the file contents, and then display it.

Then, whenever you add something to the list, also write it to the file. That, or you could go for a database, or serialization of the ComboBox model, but file reading/writing would be the easiest, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read about this solution method but I guess that will make things complicated for me. I would change the goal if I cannot find a simple solution.